# PHP Dynamic Redirection based on Users' Clicks

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

Is there any way I can achieve the following functionality in php?

I want to redirect users based on their specific user URLs.

For example:

I have a number of user urls like following:

```
http://example.com/test/user1
http://example.com/test/user2
http://example.com/test/user3
http://example.com/test/user4
```

When each user click on his url, he will get to an index.php file at `http://example.com/test/index.php`

This `index.php file` will then redirect those users based on their urls.

So the redirection scheme will be:

```
http://example.com/test/user1  ->  http://destination1.com
http://example.com/test/user2  ->  http://destination2.com
http://example.com/test/user3  ->  http://destination3.com
http://example.com/test/user4  ->  http://destination4.com
```

Comment: And what are you tried so far?

Comment: @DavidKmenta , So far I have not tried anything because I can not think how to start on it as I am not so much fluent in php.

Comment: your first step should be take a look on htaccess

Comment: .htaccess method can not work because this is a wordpress site and I can not render shortcodes in htaccess. that's why I have find a way to do this in PHP

Comment: What about http://codex.wordpress.org/User%3aAmereservant/Editing_and_Customizing_htaccess_Indirectly ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']=="/test/user1"){
header("Location:http://destination1.com");
}
else if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']=="/test/user2"){
header("Location:http://destination2.com");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without php assumming you are on apache

Create .htaccess in root of your site and add this there

```
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 /test/user1 http://destination1.com
Redirect 301 /test/user2 http://destination2.com
Redirect 301 /test/user3 http://destination3.com
Redirect 301 /test/user4 http://destination4.com
```

or on ngix

```
location /test/user1 {  
rewrite ^(.*)$ http://destination1.com redirect;  
}
location /test/user2 {
rewrite ^(.*)$ http://destination2.com redirect;
}
location /test/user3 {
rewrite ^(.*)$ http://destination3.com redirect;
}
location /test/user4 {
   rewrite ^(.*)$ http://destination4.com redirect;
}
```

learn more about redirections
https://moz.com/learn/seo/redirection

Answer (score 0):

Here is a trivial example of how you can do that. If it is a case of large amount of users then maybe you should save the `url->destination` relationship into database. You can put this code inside `/test/index.php` file, but before any output. And also in `functions.php` file of your theme, in `wp` action and actions fired later.

```
global $wp;

$users = array(
    'test/user1'  =>  'http://destination1.com',
    'test/user2'  =>  'http://destination2.com',
    'test/user3'  =>  'http://destination3.com',
    'test/user4'  =>  'http://destination4.com',
);

if ( !empty( $users[ $wp->request ] ) ) wp_redirect( $users[ $wp->request ] );
else {
    // this block of code is executed if user is not found
}
```